# Can I get the values before the underscore in the dataframe using python?

Tags: python, database, dataframe, data-analysis

**Input**

```
id  values
0   Q56_0.01 Q57_0.99
1   Q1_0.01 Q57_0.96 Q67_0.03
```

I need to get the output dataframe in the below format

**Ouput**

```
id   values
0    Q56
1    Q57
2    Q1
3    Q57
4    Q67
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
new_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['value'])
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    number_split=df.loc[index,'values'].count(' ')+1
    split_val=df.loc[index,'values']
    for value in range(number_split):
        new_row = pd.Series({'value':split_val.split(" ",number_split)[value].split("_",2)[0]},name='value')
        print(new_row)
        new_df=new_df.append(new_row,ignore_index=False)
new_df.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'ID'})
```